# Why is wp_nav_menu() not removing the container around the nav <ul>?

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes

I am trying to remove the `<div>` that wraps the `<ul>`, but when I set `'container'` to `false` or `''` the `<div>` still shows up. Why is it not being removed?

Example with `false`:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation navigation">
  <?php wp_nav_menu(
            array( 'theme_location'=> 'header-menu',
                   'menu_id' => 'header-menu',
                   'container' => false,
                   'depth' => 2, ) );
    ?>
</nav>
```

Example with `''`:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation navigation">
  <?php wp_nav_menu(
            array( 'theme_location'=> 'header-menu',
                   'menu_id' => 'header-menu',
                   'container' => '',
                   'depth' => 2, ) );
    ?>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if there are any callbacks on the `wp_nav_menu_args` or `pre_wp_nav_menu` filters?